# how I could extrude an object so that it is not a 2D object?

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode, extrude

Beginner in blender. Wanted to know how I could extrude this object so that it is not a 2D object. In other words I want to make this object able to be printed in a 3D printer.[image: Here is the object]

Comment: Try the Solidifier Modifier.

Comment: That is a good idea but I'm trying to make it into a block-like object. Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you mean a block-like as in block of wood or built out of Lego? For the first one I would start with Solidifier Modifier, apply it and then manually edit the results. For the second one look at an Emitter using Volume, Grid and Object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solidify photogrammetry model by filling it from inside?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68141/how-to-solidify-photogrammetry-model-by-filling-it-from-inside)

Comment: Please add a reference image that shows what it is that you want to get. It is hard to tel what we're looking at, and harder to guess what it should be like.

Comment: Are you saying that screenshot is of a 2d object? I totally can't tell just from the screenshot. If you want to extrude stuff, just go into edit mode, select what you want to extrude, and hit E.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, make sure that the object is properly orientated. If the object displayed is like that because it's rotated in object mode, you should be able to get it out pretty easily. If not, I suggest you read [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56882/how-do-you-rotate-an-object-so-that-a-particular-face-is-parallel-to-the-ground). You want the top flat surface to be perpendicular to the Z axis.

As for how I would go about this, with my 2D object (seen below):

[image: 2D object]

Select the bottom edges that you want to extrude.

[image: Selected edges]

Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude them and press <kbd>Z</kbd> to lock that extrusion to the Z axis. Feel free to extrude them however much you wish, just make sure that everything is extruded down so that all the highest of the selected vertices (the ones you are moving down) is below the lowest of all the other vertices. Otherwise, you'd have those coming out the bottom of your object.

[image: Extrude edges]

Press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale the selected edges, <kbd>Z</kbd> to limit scaling to the Z axis, and <kbd>0</kbd> to scale to 0.

[image: Scale on Z axis]

From this point, it's just a matter of going around, selecting the open edges of your mesh and filling them in.

[image: Fill in the gaps]

I hope this helps and if you have trouble, let me know in the comments.